# Time complexity of the given C function theta(nlogn) or theta(n^2logn)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I have calculated the time complexity of the following C function and it is coming to `theta (nlogn)`.Can you tell me whether i am wrong,the answer given was `theta(n^2logn)`?I have just started reading about these concepts.

```
int unk(int n)
{
  int i,j,k=0;
  for(i=n/2;i<=n;i++)
     for(j=2;j<=n;j=j*2)
        k=k+(n/2);
  return k;
}
```

What I have done is:The outer loop executes for `(n/2+2)` times,inner loop executes for `(n/2+1)(logn+1)` times and the statement in the body of the loop executes `(n/2+1)(logn)` times.So the total running time comes to `theta(nlogn)`.(Assume all the costs to be 1 and the log to be a binary logarithm).

Comment: Theorethical questions are probably a better fit for [cs.se].


Comment: Can you tell us the name of the book?

Comment: I have summed up those times which i have obtained for the two loops and the statement.I am not getting the n^2 term.

Comment: I got this question from a certain website(I don't remember the name) where the answer was n^2logn.

Answer (score 4):

I think your answer is right, it is theta(nlogn) indeed. However, your analysis seems somewhat wrong.

The outer loop executes O(n/2) times.

The inner loop executes O(logn) times per iteration of the outer loop.

By multiplying the two and dropping the constants, you arrive at `O(n) * O(logn) = O(nlogn)`.

Comment: Yes,the outer loop executes for (n/2)+1+1 times(the last 1 is for execution before termination of the loop).So each of (lgn+1) times of the inner loop get executed for (n/2+1) times of the outer loop.Therefore the statement inside the loop gets executed for (n/2+1)lgn times.

Comment: Summing up (n/2+2)+(n/2+1)(lgn+1)+(n/2+1)lgn gives theta(nlgn)

Comment: Well what can I say, thats not how you calculate the complexity. You don't add things up that way.